# Reactjs hook that uses other hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I needed to create a custom hook which is supposed to contain all the handlers that will be used everywhere in my page. My requirements were;

1. Handlers are supposed to be accessible from all the components in the page
2. Handlers should be able to use other hooks, like useContext

So, created a **useHandlers** hook [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-sunset-e0x60?file=/src/index.tsx)

However, couldn't make the LogHandler accessible from the page, receving **LogHandler is not a function**

Any idea?

Comment: Try to change `LogHandler` to `logHandler`. React consider `LogHandler` as a component, not function. CMIIW

Comment: @Kaslie no, `React` doesn't care if you name something with an uppercase or lowercase and it doesn't consider everything that starts with an uppercase a component. However, you shouldn't be using `PascalCase` for things that are not components.

Comment: @goto1 thank you for your correction. and for the problem, let me trying to answer because I'm not a typescript developer, `let LogHandler: () => void` what is this line mean ? does it mean LogHandler function that return void ? or LogHandler is a void ?. If the LogHandler is a void, then u can't run it as a function. Beside that, I've tried to edit the code in the sandbox, by change to `const LogHandler = () => {}`, the error when `return { HandlerComp, LogHandler }` gone

Comment: @Kaslie correct, the `LogHandler` function is not initialized, hence the error. The `LogHandler: () => void` is basically a way, in `TypeScript`, to say that the function doesn't take any parameters and doesn't return anything (`void`), but it's not an initialization step, so it is `undefined`, that's why the error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue why you're getting `LogHandler is not a function` is because it's `undefined` and it doesn't get initialized until `HandlerComp` gets called:

```
export const userHandlers = (): IUseHandlers => {
  // initialization skipped, so `LogHandler` is undefined
  let LogHandler: () => void;

  const HandlersComp: React.FunctionComponent<HandlersProps> = (
    props: HandlersProps
  ) => {
    // initialized here, but that's after `HandlersComp` gets caled
    LogHandler = () => {
      console.log("Hi from LogHandler");
    };

    return <></>;
  };
  return { HandlersComp, LogHandler };
}
```

I suggest you move the initialization step from `HandlersComp` like so:

```
export const useHandlers = (): IUseHandlers => {
  const LogHandler: () => void = () => {
    console.log("Hi from LogHandler");
  };

  const HandlersComp: React.FunctionComponent<HandlersProps> = (
    props: HandlersProps
  ) => {
    LogHandler()
    return <></>;
  };

  return { HandlersComp, LogHandler };
};
```

---

Some notes:

- `HandlersComp` looks like it should be a separate and reusable component, rather than a `hook`
- `LogHandler` also looks more like a utility function, rather than a `hook`
- `LogHandler` shouldn't be using `PascalCase` for naming as that should be "reserved" for `React` components; `HandlersComp` is fine, since it looks like it's a component